# Cycle in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Given a tree, we have to find two nodes, so that after connecting those nodes, cycle formed will be longest.

I was thinking in terms of finding diameter of a tree. So , is this the right approach, or is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: If you want the longest cycle, yes diameter of tree is what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a diameter and connect its ultimate points. You can find an algorithm e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-tree-using-dfs/)